# Javascript running same line twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

This occurs within my react app using immutable.js. Basically, inside this component's `render` function, it reaches a line such as

```
1. foo.get('attr')
```

And console looks like:

```
foo is not defined       file.js:1
```

where `foo` is supposed to be an `Immutable.Map`. After attempting to log `foo` before it's used I find that foo actually is defined as an `Immutable.Map`. That's strange...my code now looks like:

```
1. console.log(foo)
2. foo.get('attr')
```

And console looks like

```
Immutable.Map { ... }    file.js:1
foo is not defined       file.js:2
```

Next, I attempt to log `foo.get('attr')` and my code looks like:

```
1. console.log(foo)
2. console.log(foo.get('attr'))
3. foo.get('attr')
```

and console looks like:

```
Immutable.Map { ... }    file.js:1
'value'                  file.js:2
foo is not defined       file.js:2
```

---

I know this is generic code with specific libraries, but I was wondering if anyone knew how this was happening? It looks like a line is running twice and I didn't think this was possible.

Comment: Can you show the entire render()

Comment: There's a good chance you are inadvertently calling a function when you are supposed to just be referencing it for setting up a callback. This would happen by adding `()` to the end of the function name where only a reference is needed.